# Mbuni build error adding symbols: Bad value

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, kannel

Im trying to make mbuni in ubuntu 16.04, but im following their standard documentation , im executing the following command

```
cd mbuni-version
./bootstrap
./configure --with-cflags=-fPIC --enable-shared
make install
```

but still getting the following error :

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --mode=link --tag=CC gcc  -g -O2 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_BSD_SOURCE -O4 -Wall -D_REENTRANT=1 -fPIC -D_LARGE_FILES= -I/usr/local/include/kannel -g -O2 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_BSD_SOURCE -fPIC -D_LARGE_FILES= -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/openssl  -rdynamic -L/usr/local/lib/kannel -lgw -lwap -lgwlib -lssl -lrt -lresolv -lnsl -lm  -lpthread -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto -lssl  -o libmms.la -rpath /usr/local/lib  mms_eventlogger.lo mms_mmbox.lo mms_msg.lo mms_queue.lo mms_strings.lo mms_uaprof.lo mms_util.lo mms_mm7soap.lo mms_cfg.lo  -lwap -lgwlib -lpthread -ldl  -L/usr/local/lib/kannel -lgw -lwap -lgwlib -lssl -lrt -lresolv -lnsl -lm  -lpthread -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto -lssl
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/mms_eventlogger.o .libs/mms_mmbox.o .libs/mms_msg.o .libs/mms_queue.o .libs/mms_strings.o .libs/mms_uaprof.o .libs/mms_util.o .libs/mms_mm7soap.o .libs/mms_cfg.o   -L/usr/local/lib/kannel -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -ldl -lgw -lwap -lgwlib -lrt -lresolv -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lxml2 -lcrypto -lssl  -g -O2 -O4 -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libmms.so.0 -o .libs/libmms.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/kannel/libwap.a(wsp_headers.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/kannel/libwap.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

what to do to get around the error to make and install properly ?

Comment: I think it's saying you need to recombile `libwab.a` with the same options.

Comment: libwab.a is a part of kannel and i have built kannel with same option but still have no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's quick workaround helped me with compiling Mbuni for Ubuntu 16.04

```
# NOTE : It's just a quick recipe that not verified in real production
#
# Compile and install Kannel 1.5.0
#
tar jvxf gateway-1.5.0.tar.bz2
cd ./gateway-1.5.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/kannel
make
make install
#
# Compile and install Mbuni 1.6.0
#
cd ..
tar zvxf mbuni-1.6.0.tar.gz
cd mbuni-1.6.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mbuni --with-kannel-dir=/usr/local/kannel --disable-shared
make
make install
```

I got similar error when compiled mbuni without **--disable-shared** option.